# Why clustering does not work? (google maps API V3)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, cluster-analysis, markerclusterer

I just started using the version 3 of the google maps api, and i am making a simple implementation of clustering, but i cant make it work. Maybe you can see where is my error, and help me making it work:

```
var map;

function runmap() {
        //Prepare cordinates
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        //Prepare other options
        var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        //,disableDefaultUI: true//Uncoment to disable map controls
        };

        //Prepare map using de destination id(in the html page) and the options
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

        //Adding markers(Search marker options for more options)
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatlng, 
         map: map,
         title:"Zdravo",
         icon:"djole.png"//Change the icon of the marker
         });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.597, 150.744), 
         map: map,
         title:"Zdravo",
         icon:"djole.png"//Change the icon of the marker
         });

         var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.290, 150.444), 
         map: map,
         title:"Zdravo",
         icon:"djole.png"//Change the icon of the marker
         });


        var markers = [];
    markers.push(marker);
    markers.push(marker2);
    markers.push(marker3);
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    }
```

**Update**
This is the error i see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/) or [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/)  for Google API version 3. It looks like you are using MarkerClusterer for Google Maps API version 2.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you have loaded all the needed libraries (included the one for the clustering) and you get no JS errors. If that is not so and you have doubts, please report all the errors you get and libraries you load.

Try to supply maxZoom level:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { maxZoom: 10 });
```

Then when you see the map, zoom out and check if it would group the markers.

Comment: What other extra libraries i need? Are the same as for Markers and Info windows? If yes, sure i already have them there. I tried with the zoom but still don't see the clustering.

Comment: You also need the "marker clusterer" library, its a plugin, not a default gmaps behavior. See here along with working examples (that are few lines of code that works - copy source of one of them to your file and start debugging from there): http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/

Comment: I just added that library but i get some error, i dont understand why. See image above

Comment: Provide full page source where you get the error or link to it.